# Check if file exists on Dropbox using Android Dropbox API

Tags: java, android, dropbox-api

I'm not an experienced Java/Android developer and I'm trying to check if a file exists on Dropbox using Dropbox API for Android.

I don't manage to find any method in the API to check this. The only way I found how to do this is to use `try ... catch` and catch the `DropboxServerException`, which in my opinion is very ugly.

Is there a nicer way, like `if (file.exists)`, to check if the file exists ?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share the code you tried? Also, `try-catch` is simply for error-handling, so in case your code fails you can handle the `exception` properly. Usually you use `try-catch`es in blocks that could fail (like connections to internet, reading/writing files, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [`metadata`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)) and looking for an exception with a 404 response is probably the best way to check the existence of a single file in Dropbox.

Depending on what you're trying to do, there are likely better approaches:

1. If you're enumerating all files anyway (e.g. using delta), then there's no need to ask the server whether a file exists, because you can keep track yourself.
2. If you're trying to read the file, go ahead and try to read it (and handle the exception if it doesn't exist).

Note that this kind of (pseudo-)code is always buggy:

```
if (file.exists()) {
    file.read();
}
```

What happens if the file is deleted in between when you check for its existence and when you try to read it? You'll get a 404 and an exception when you try to read the file. So you'll need code that handles that... which means that the first check for file existence doesn't do anything for you. You may as well skip it (and the corresponding round-trip to the server).

Comment: Ended up using try...catch ... Still don't like it, but I guess it's the java way ...